# How to make the XML pass the XSD validation when using the default namespaces not explicitly defined in XML but present in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XML whose validation fails due to the following issue:
The Prefix "example" For Element "example:lotNumber" Is Not Bound., Line '4', Column '19'.
The Prefix "example" For Element "example:lotNumber" Is Not Bound.

I have declared the namespaces in the XSD since it is a default namespace it need not be included in XML again. How to make the XML pass the validation against the XSD?

do not wish to include the namespaces in XML `<note xmlns:example="urn:example:mda:">` as it is a default namespace. I want to ensure the XML passes the validation even if I do not include the default namespaces in XML.

Following is my XML:
Following is my XML and XSD:

```xml
<note >
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<example:lotNumber>XML DEFAULT</example:lotNumber>
</note>
```

Following is the XSD containing default namespace:

```xml
Folloiwng is XSD:
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:example="urn:example:mda:">
  <xs:element name="note">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="to"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="from"/>
<xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Also this just an example but the `example` can include any element such as:
example:helloXML DEFAULT NEW NEW ONE</example:hello>
example:hello1XML DEFAULT NEW NEW ONE</example:hello1>

Hence I cannot include the `lotNumber` in the XSD and make it pass the values are user-defined so it can be anything. How to make the XML pass the XSD validation when not included default namespace.

If I include the namespace in XML then it would work fine but user can skip then also it should pass:

```xml
<note xmlns:example="urn:example:mda:">
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<example:lotNumber>XML DEFAULT NEW NEW ONE</example:lotNumber>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with the schema. Before being even considered suitable for validation using the schema, your XML has to be well-formed, and if it contains an undeclared namespace prefix then it is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah I agree, but the users can provide this kind of XML. We are a bit restricted as it's the default namespace they are allowed to do. Hence, wanted to confirm how to handle these kinds of XML and pass the XSD validation.

Comment: This isn't a "kind of XML", it's non-XML. If you want to allow your users to provide stuff that isn't XML, then you need to write a specification for exactly what they are allowed to provide, and write a parser for it. If I were you, I would stick to requiring standards-conformant data, it makes everyone's life easier.